# boost ptree modify an array of values on the fly

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

I started using the ptree and the json parser from boost to save some quick information. 
The problem is that I only need to save some URI, so I don't care about a key.
Now I want to find a certain value and remove it.
How can I do this

```
{
    "MyArray":
     [
              "value1",
              "value2"
     ]
}
```

I can't use `find()` and iterators don't seem to work.

```
for (it ; it != myptree.end();  ++it)
    if ((*it).second.data.compare(strValueImSearching) != 0)
    // the previous line is not valid from .data
         myptree.erase(it);
```

Comment: I found a work around, but not sure it's the best way. 
http://pastebin.com/s2HH2UgS

Comment: That actually made it clear. I edited the confusing title. You have no problem "querying an array of values". Also, iterators work. But not once invalidated. See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ah. Lightbulb moment.

You cannot iterate a collection that's changing like that, because the `erase` calls invalidate the current iterator.

> See here for iterator invalidation rules: [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Instead, indeed use stable iterators:

```
while (it != myptree.end()) {
     if ((*it).second.data.compare(strValueImSearching) != 0)
         it = myptree.erase(it);
     else
         ++it;
}
```